# Prove if $f$ have maximun point in $c$ then $D^+f(c)\leq 0$ and $D_{-}f(c) \geq 0$

Tags: measure-theory

Prove if $f$ have maximun point in $c$ then $D^+f(c)\leq 0$ and $D_{-}f(c) \geq 0$

**My attempt:**
We know by definition:

$D^+f(c)=\displaystyle\limsup_{h\rightarrow c^+}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}$

$D_{-}f(c)=\displaystyle\liminf_{h\rightarrow c^-}\frac{f(c)-f(c+h)}{h}$

Moreover, if f have a maximum point $c$ then $\forall x$ we have $f(x)\leq c$

Here i'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Comment: Show that there exist "left" and "right" neighborhoods where the function is increasing and decreasing respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that $f$ has local maximum at $c$. For then some $\delta_{0}>0$ is such that $f(x)\leq f(c)$ for $x\in(c-\delta_{0},c+\delta_{0})$. Then for $0<h<\delta_{0}$, $c+h\in(c-\delta_{0},c+\delta_{0})$ and hence $f(c+h)-f(c)\leq 0$, $\dfrac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}\leq 0$ for all such $h$, then $\sup_{0<h<\delta_{0}}\dfrac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}\leq 0$ and hence $D^{+}f(c)=\inf_{\delta>0}\sup_{0<h<\delta}\dfrac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}\leq\sup_{0<h<\delta_{0}}\dfrac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}\leq 0$.

Comment: Excellent proof. Thanks